# How does the Yogi Remember his previous births?

Tags: scripture, yoga, rebirth

The Yogi has the knowledge of all incarnations.

How does he dissolve the veils of separation from one incarnation to the next?

Comment: There is something called Sukshma Sharira(subtle body) which works like a Hard Disk of Computer.

Comment: @YDS If I understand correctly,The question isn't how Yogi remembers the incarnations. It is how he is able to dissolve the separation or cope up with the separation. The OP is aware that Yogi is aware of his previous births. It was clear from his title and first line of the body. Or did I understand it wrong? Also give a reason while you are changing the title. It helps for understanding.

Comment: It is in Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms.

Comment: "**The Yogi Remembers**" looks a Question...? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @FrankHestermann Can you please correct the title if it's not appropriate?

Comment: @YDS You should first get clarification while making major changes to the title or body and not edit and then ask them to correct. I think the question is how he will be able to cope up with the different births if he remembers all the births. "The Yogi remembers" is ok if you ask me. The title need not to be asking question. It should be just clear.The body should ask the question. It is done in this case. So, first ask clarification and then make major edits.

Comment: If one answers how that's fantastic if no answer then it should be returned to " The Yogi

Comment: Your initial Q was extremely unclear for me, now it is clear but I don't think it is the Q that you wanted to ask? @FrankHestermann

Comment: @Rickross What he meant is, how can a yogi keep a stack of his reincarnations so that at any point of time he can differentiate them.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Patanjali Yoga Sutras (with translation and commentary by Swami Vivekananda)](http://www.yogaincentro.it/uploads/file/PatanjaliYogaSutraSwamiVivekanandaSanEng.pdf) a Yogi can know past and future by employing a technique called Samayana. To know what Samayana is you just need to go through the Vibhuti Pada section of that text.

In short, Dharana, Dhyanam and Samadhi, when done at the same time, is called Samayana.

Sutra 16 of this Chapter states:

> parinamatrayasanyamadatitanagatajnanam ||
>
> By making Samyama on the three sorts of changes comes the knowledge of
>   past and future

Sutra 18 again says:

> sanskarasakshatkaranat poorvajatijnanam ||
>
> By perceiving the impressions, knowledge of past life.

The commentary on this verse by Swami Vivekananda is as follows:

> Each experience that we have comes in the form of a wave in the
>   Chitta, and this subsides and becomes finer and finer, but is never
>   lost. It remains there in minute form, and if we can bring this wave
>   up again, it becomes memory. So, if the Yogi can make a Samyama on
>   these past impressions in the mind, he will begin to remember all his
>   past lives.

Apart from that, according to Manu Smriti, one can acquire the faculty of remembering one's past lives even by performing Vedic studies, austerities etc. Here is the verse:

> Manu Smriti 4.148. By daily reciting the Veda, by (the observance of
>   the rules of) purification, by (practising) austerities, and by doing
>   no injury to created beings, **one (obtains the faculty of)
>   remembering former births.**

Comment: giving reference is fine, But if you can add a proper analysis, that would be great. Because this question is more into analysis and less into references.

Comment: if one refuses to accept any gifts for 12 years, he can remember is past lives. because by accepting gifts we also accept the giver's karma. and that clouds our own memory.

Comment: Ok .. not accepting gifts for so long may also form one austerity and austerity is also one of the means as mentioned in Manu Smriti @mar

Comment: @Rickross - there are many austerities but this specific one *apratigraha* is specifically mentioned by Vivekananda cos he was able to recall.

Comment: Ok .. yes .... @mar