# How does the soul get the memory of past lives?

Tags: belief, rebirth, jiva

In this life one forgets the past lives, now if someone dies how can they remember the past lives? As it is said in the womb one remembers all their past lives.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How does the Yogi Remember his previous births?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28385/647)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto there it has shown methods etc, but what about one who doesn't do these they still get it?

Comment: Like if someone died will they know all their lives? or just one @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: It is not possible for a normal human. Read [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/why-dont-we-remember-our-past-lives#comment5974_3277)

Comment: It is a great mercy that we cannot remember our previous births; the trials and tribulations of one life are difficult enough.