# Why is it forbidden to recall our past life's journey?

Tags: vedas

Why and what could possibly happen if one were to recall their past life? Keeping in mind about reincarnation seen in several cases all over the world how come they regained the memories?

Comment: Where did you read that it is forbidden?

Comment: Here are a couple of related posts --1. (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28385/4732) and 2. (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28842)

Comment: @Rickross I have not read but I heard it from someone  but yes thankyou.

Comment: @Rickross do you still remember that post where there was a discussion on gandharvas

Comment: I'd like to discuss something

Comment: No I don't remember .. which post about Gandharvas?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28116/scripture-showing-ways-to-summon-gandharva-yaksha-and-kinnar. @Rickross about this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138991/discussion-between-user28167-and-rickross).